# nodejs mongodb chrome exposed password potential databreach fix

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am using mongodb with nodejs on a web app using chrome as my browser. When I login to my system it authenticates via passport.js. But chrome sees this as an exposed password. What should I do to prevent this. Do I need to add something like B crypt on top of the passport.js? So the password does not get exposed and chrome does not give this warning.

After a successful login and re routing to my main page the error occurs but, my login was successful

Routes

```js
router.get("/main",isLoggedIn,function(req,res)
{
    res.render("main");
});
//Login logic
router.post("/signin", passport.authenticate("local",
    {
        successRedirect : "/main",
        failureRedirect : "/signup"
    }),function(req, res){
    
});
```

Passport setup

```js
//Setup passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//Serialize user and deseriallize user allows for encoding and decoding
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
```

My signin form going into the route:

```
<form action = "/signin" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <button>Sign in</button>
</form>
```

If there is anything else you need to answer this question please ask.

Comment: Is it not because you are using a basic password for testing? Google will give you a warning if you're using some basic password for testing like "test123" or whatever in Chrome regardless of what your app does.

Comment: ah yes I was using that for testing it. I have changed it and it works. Feels like a silly mistake to make, be good if chrome would inform you of the error details. Feel free to post as an answer for other users as it might save someone some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using a basic password for testing. Google will give you a warning if you're using some basic password for testing like "test123" or whatever in Chrome regardless of what your app does.

You do not need to manually encrypt the password when using a passport.js local strategy.